# How to use httpd.conf to lock down ONLY index.php at the root, not index.php files in subdirectories

Tags: php, apache

Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard x64 Edition Service Pack 2, Apache 2.4.4, PHP 5.4.16 (x86)

Most of my directories contain an index.php file which I have set up as the DirectoryIndex using the httpd.conf file.

Here is some text from my httpd.conf file

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/subdirectory">
    Options -Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Files "index.php">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "srvname"
    AuthUserFile "C:/wamp/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

The above configuration results in **both** servername/subdirectory/index.php and servername/index.php prompting for a User Name and Password.

Trying to get more specific with the Files directive, like below, results in **neither** servername/subdirectory/index.php nor servername/index.php prompting for a password.

```
<Files "C:/wamp/www/index.php">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "srvname"
    AuthUserFile "C:/wamp/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

All I am really trying to accomplish here is to password protect my WampServer configuration page.  Can someone please tell me how to use the Files directive in httpd.conf specifically on C:/wamp/www/index.php without locking down ALL of my index.php pages?

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache.conf file, it should have this:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
```

It's the thing that hides files starting in ".ht" everywhere.